# load json file before app startup and save it in global variable mithrilJs

Tags: javascript, configuration, routes, runtime, mithril.js

I want to load a JSON file into my mithrilJs app before its startup and want to save this data in some global variable (JSON file is for some run time configuration of mithril application just like *app_initializer* in Angular) 
so far I have done this in my app

```
import m from 'mithril';
import { a } from './MainView';

var Data = {


    fetch: function() {
        m.request({
            method: "GET",
            url: "./client/config/config.json",
        })
            .then(function(items) {
                console.log(items)
                 // want to store this
                m.route(document.body, "/accounts", a)

            })
    }

}
Data.fetch()
```

and my Main view file contains

```
 import m from 'mithril';

 import {Layout} from "./components/layout";
 import {Accounts} from "./components/accounts";
 import {AccountNew} from './components/newAccount';
 export const a={
    "/accounts": {
        render: function (vnode) {

            return m(Layout, m(Accounts))
        }
    },
    "/accountsNew": {
        render: function (vnode) {
            return m(Layout, m(AccountNew))
        }
    },
}
```

so what could be better approach for this and also I want to store fetched json file data (items) in some global variable like props in react or services in angular , How I can do that to access everywhere in my app

Answer (score 1):

The docs state that you can use onmatch to preload data, here is a rough translation of their example:

```
var state = {
    items: null,
    loadItems: function() {
        if (state.items === null) {
            return m.request("./client/config/config.json").then(function(items) {
                state.items = items;
            });
        }
    }
};

const a = {
    "/accounts": {
        onmatch: state.loadItems,
        render: function (vnode) {
            return m(Layout, m(Accounts))
        }
    },
    "/accountsNew": {
        onmatch: state.loadItems,
        render: function (vnode) {
            return m(Layout, m(AccountNew))
        }
    },
}
```

You can read their two examples in the documentation here: [Preloading data](https://mithril.js.org/route.html#preloading-data).

**Alternative solutions**

These solutions don't really involve mithril because your are really loading the data before mithril is even used.  You should be able to pass your state variable into the component as an attribute, ie. `return m(Layout, m(Accounts, {state}));`

*Dumping JSON String into server side template*

If you control the server side as well you can just dump your configuration directly into a global variable by outputting an escaped JSON string assigned to a javascript variable in your base template.  I do this to dump model information or session information so my client side code can use it.

```html
<script> var config = ${escapedJSONStringInServerVariable};</script>
```

*Import config directly*

You can also just import the configuration directly into your app if you rewrite your config.json to just export your configuration as an object.

`import {Config} from ./client/config/config.js`

*Call `m.request` directly*

Finally you can also just assign the promise returned from `m.request` to a var and return that promise in `loadItems`.  This should fire m.request immediately but prevent the loading of your templates until the promise is resolved.

```
var state = (function () {
    var configRequest = m.request({
        url: "./client/config/config.json"
    }).then(function(items) {
        state.items = items;
    });
    return {
        items: null,
        loadItems: function() {
            return configRequest;
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Can I store it in global variable so that its accessible everywhere well I don't want it on component init I want to load before app start. @Ian

Comment: I added some alternative solutions but it really depends on the architecture of your app.  Especially since you are wanting to load it before the mithril router is used.

Comment: I've made a singleton class and store  config there @Ian

Answer (score 0):

Try to save it in sessionStorage and check it after every reload.

```
if(!sessionStorage.key('myJson'))
     sessionStorage.setItem('myJson','myJson')
```

Comment: I dont want to use session or local storage @Vladimir